# call a method of backingbean when finished filtering the table ends

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Call a method of backingbean when finished filtering the table ends. Using **Primefaces**, datatable look like this:

```
<p:dataTable id="tabla_gral" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.verTabla}" var="item" paginator="true" rows="15" rowKey="#{item.no}" value="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumo}" filteredValue="#{consumoMaterial.listadoConsumoFiltered}">
  <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{consumoMaterial.actualizarSaldos}" update=":form2:tabla_gral" />
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Búsqueda de Consumo por: #{consumoMaterial.tipoBuscar}: '#{consumoMaterial.codigo}'" />
  </f:facet>
  <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.no}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.no}" id="cclave" sortBy="#{item.no}" filterBy="#{item.no}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Nro" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.no}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.centroCosto}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.centroCosto}" id="cconcepto" sortBy="#{item.centroCosto}" filterBy="#{item.centroCosto}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Centro de Costo" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.centroCosto}" />
  </p:column>
  <p:column exportable="#{consumoMaterial.codigoAlmacen}" rendered="#{consumoMaterial.codigoAlmacen}" id="ctipo" sortBy="#{item.codigoAlmacen}" filterBy="#{item.codigoAlmacen}" filterMatchMode="contains">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="Almacén" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.codigoAlmacen}" />
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

`ajax event="filter"` does not work because is while filtering not when it finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can: in filter event, you call JavaScript function in oncomplete or onsuccess(it depend on your target), the JavaScript function will fire click event to commandbutton, and you put action code you want to that commandbutton:

```
<h:form id="form">  
    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function test(){
                        $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:btn')).click();
                    }
                </script>
                <p:commandButton  style="display:none !important" id="btn" oncomplete="alert('ab');" value="SB"/>
                <p:dataTable   var="carr" value="#{tabview.l1}" id="carList" >  
                    <p:ajax event="filter" oncomplete="test();"/>
                    <p:column filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="#{carr.model}" headerText="Model" style="width:30%">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{carr.model}" />  
                    </p:column>  
                    <p:column headerText="MANUFAC" style="width:20%">  
                        <h:outputText value="#{carr.manufacturer}" />  
                    </p:column>  
                </p:dataTable>
 </h:form>
```